# How to reduce the vertical space of acronym lists in LaTeX?

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, acronyms

I am using the `acronym` package to generate list of abbreviations in LaTeX. Here is sample snippet.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\begin{document}

Some text \ac{USA}

\section{List of Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
 \item \acro{USA}{United States of America}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

However, there is a huge distance between the abbreviation lists and how can we reduce the vertical space? I tried `\itemsep0pt` but it didn't help at all.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear why itemsep is not working for you but it could be a combination of other items in your envinonments. See the following and compare with your own document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\begin{document}

Some legal text \ac{AE} \ac{MX} \ac{TZ} \ac{UK} \ac{UM} \ac{US}

\section{List of Acronyms}
Without defining item separation
\begin{acronym}[FOUR] % [FOUR] can be any word to show the indent
\item %remove this if you dont want a space between header and first item
\acro{AE}{United Arab Emirates}
\acro{MX}{United Mexican States}
\acro{TZ}{United Republic of Tanzania}
\acro{UK}{United Kingdom (of Great Britain and Northern Ireland)}
\acro{UM}{United States (Minor Outlying Islands)}
\acro{US}{United States (of America)}
\end{acronym}
\vspace{1cm}
With itemsep=-5pt
\begin{acronym}[FOUR]\itemsep=-5pt
\acro{AE}{United Arab Emirates}
\acro{MX}{United Mexican States}
\acro{TZ}{United Republic of Tanzania}
\acro{UK}{United Kingdom (of Great Britain and Northern Ireland)}
\acro{UM}{United States (Minor Outlying Islands)}
\acro{US}{United States (of America)}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```